# Reading the last element of a json file in a blob storage

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-blob-storage

Say I want to read the last element of a `json` file in order to do an Azure blob aggregation test. So the simple, totally non-efficient way is to download[toStream] the whole file, and check if the last element is what we had expected, but is there any other more efficient way to do this?

Comment: while uploading you can update the metadata property of the blob with the last element value, so when you need it you can do 'listblobswithmetdata' and make the decision.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are large and have a predefined size range, you could try using offset byte ranges to stream only the part of the blobs.

This is still not very efficient. Instead, the best option would be to also use blob metadata to track important workflow properties within the files, as mentioned by another commenter.